# Continue Loop if Term is in an Array (odd result)

Tags: php, phpexcel

The script in question takes an excel file of language vocabulary (French to English, etc) and creates XML (zips and downloads) to format a crossword generator we use.

It works, but I've been asked to remove any duplicate terms as an enhancement. Below is the original code in full, and then the new code to skip duplicate terms. With the new code, everything runs, but it creates a corrupt ZIP. Please see the before and after code and tell me what is going on:

Full before working code:

```
<?php

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** PHPExcel */
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

/** Functions */
require_once 'zip.php';
require_once 'named_to_number.php';

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} 

/** Create Excel Object using PHPExcel **/
$inputFileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

/** Get how many rows **/
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();

/** Keeps track of chapters to make new files on change **/
$chapter = -1;

/** For keeping track of the files created to zip & delete. **/
$files_to_zip = array();

/** Iterates through every row, writing data from cells into XML files. **/
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {

    //remove spaces
    $term = str_replace(' ', '', $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());

    //skip terms if they are too long or contain a non-alpha character.
    if (strlen($term) >= 17 || !preg_match('/^\p{L}+$/ui', $term)) {
        continue;
    }

    //translates accented characters to numbered HTML code
    $term = named_to_number(htmlentities($term, ENT_SUBSTITUTE , 'UTF-8'));

    /** Checks first column to see if the chapter has changed. 
    If it has, the current file will be closed and a new one opened. **/
    if ($chapter != $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue()){
        fwrite ($f, "</words>\n</content>");
        fclose($f);

        if (strlen($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue()) < 2) {
            $filename = 'ch0' . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue() . '.xml';
        } else {
            $filename = 'ch' . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue() . '.xml';
        }

        $f = fopen($filename, 'a');
        /** Add to the list of files to zip and delete **/
        array_push($files_to_zip, $filename);
        fwrite ($f, "<content>\n<words>\n");
        /** Update chapter value **/
        $chapter = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
    }

    /** Write terms **/
    $data = 
        "<word><entry>" . $term . 
        "</entry><clue>" . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue() . 
        "</clue></word>\n";
    fwrite ($f, $data);
}

fwrite ($f, "</words>\n</content>");
fclose($f);

/** Removes any blank ch.xml files **/
if(($key = array_search('ch.xml', $files_to_zip)) !== false) {
    unset($files_to_zip[$key]);
    unlink('chapter.htm');
}

$zip = create_zip($files_to_zip, 'crossword.zip');

foreach($files_to_zip as &$del){
    unlink($del);
}

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=crossword.zip");
header("Content-type: application/zip");
readfile("crossword.zip");
unlink("crossword.zip");

?>
```

Relevant snippet where code was added (comments only related to new code):

```
//array to be used to hold terms to check against
$used = array();


for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {


    $term = str_replace(' ', '', $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());
    //Add term to running array to check against to see if it exists
    array_push($used, $term);

    //Added a third condition to check the array to see if the term exists. I have also tried this using isset with array_flip.
    if (strlen($term) >= 17 || !preg_match('/^\p{L}+$/ui', $term) || in_array($term, $used)) {
        continue;
    }
```

Again, the odd thing is that the script runs, but it just produces a bad zip. It is definitely that third conditional that is tripping the script up. I have tried it in its own if statement (just to be sure the syntax was right), but the problem persists.

Please help!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: I think once the in_array evaluates to true, it continues through until done. I tried the in_array using a hard coded term I knew was in the third row, and once it hits that term it stops.

Comment: Okay figured it out. I have to array_push after the condition. I feel dumb.